# Fake installization in django

Tags: django

When I install django (pip install django) the cmd say Requirement already satisfied

but when I do this (django-admin --version) to get the version the cmd say

'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try "pip freeze". Is Django listed there?

Comment: use `python manage.py` same thing